# MySql update error in SQL string

Tags: mysql, jsp

Not sure why, but MySQL keeps erroring with a syntax issue. I don't see any issues in the below SQL statement. But it keeps erroring during this simple update statement.

```
public static void updateTable1(Car cars){
    try ( Connection con = JdbcUtil.getConnection()) {
        String sql = "UPDATE CARS_TABLE T SET TUNING_PERFORM = "
                + "SELECT R.BORE * R.STROKE  "
                + "FROM ENGING_DERIVE R "
                + "WHERE T.ID = R.ID;"
                ;

        try (Statement st = con.createStatement()) {
            System.out.println(sql);
            int res = st.executeUpdate(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("ERROR", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The mysql syntax error statement is:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT R.BORE * R.STROKE  FROM ENGING_DERIVE R ' at line 1
```

Comment: Inner queries in general have to be put inside parenthesis. However, for a question like this, you should really try to specify what you have tried to isolate the error yourself. Just from reading it, I guess a '(' before SELECT and ')' after R.ID might do the trick, but MySQL and inner queries can sometimes be an even larger pain than they are in SQL in general.

Comment: Trying to update a table above. Only when I use Update with a Select in the string above, MySQL throws an exception. Insert into with Select statements work fine.

Comment: I forgot to add the parenthesis.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It does not work like that. Better use a JOIN instead

```
UPDATE CARS_TABLE T 
JOIN ENGING_DERIVE R ON T.ID = R.ID
SET T.TUNING_PERFORM = R.BORE * R.STROKE
```